# Regex: a number vs. a backreference to a capture group

Tags: regex, numbers, conditional-statements, backreference

I've been studying regular expressions, and I'm scratching my head on this one. On this page (https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) I see that, in a conditional regex, a reference to a numbered backreference is just a number. For example,

```
(a)?b(?(1)c|d)
```

How does regex know that we aren't supposed to match the number "1" instead of the backreference to the 1st capture group? Previously in the lessons I had learned that a backreference would be escaped, such as \1, \2, etc.

Comment: Special syntax `?(#)` right after `(`

Comment: Thank you! If you post your reply as an answer, I'll mark it accordingly.

Comment: What if someone actually wanted to match the literal 1 this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the regex tutorial you're following:

> A special construct `(?ifthen|else)` allows you to create **conditional regular expressions**. If the if part evaluates to true, then the regex engine will attempt to match the then part. Otherwise, the else part is attempted instead. *The syntax consists of a pair of parentheses.* **The opening bracket must be followed by a question mark**, immediately followed by the if part, immediately followed by the then part. This part can be followed by a vertical bar and the else part. You may omit the else part, and the vertical bar with it.

Alternatively, you can check in the if part whether a **capturing group** has taken part in the match thus far. **Place the number of the capturing group inside parentheses**, and use that as the if part.

Your second question is this:

[RegEx Demo of `\b(a)?b(?(1)c|d)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/THFwS1/1)

Note that I have added word boundary to avoid matching string like `abd` partially.

> What if someone actually wanted to match the literal 1 this way?
>
> valid input: `1c` or `d` invalid input: `1d`

That would be:

```
\b(1)?(?(1)c|d)\b
```

Comment: What if you wanted to test if the literal 1 exists in a string?

Comment: Can you please tell me a valid and invalid input examples?

Comment: valid input = ```1c``` or ```d```
invalid input = ```1d```
So, this wouldn't work right?...  ```(?(1)c|d)```

Comment: Looks like I would need to do something like this ```(1)?(?(1)c|d)```

Comment: Yes indeed `\b(1)?(?(1)c|d)\b`